# PHP is blocking other requests - session is not started

Tags: php, session

I have three PHP scripts:

test1.php:

```
<?php

sleep(3);
```

test2.php:

```
<?php

sleep(2);
```

test3.php:

```
<?php

sleep(1);
```

A simple HTML script:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.ajax({url: 'test1.php'});
$.ajax({url: 'test2.php'});
$.ajax({url: 'test3.php'});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm requesting the HTML via PHP's Built-in web server and see the following:
[image: Waterfall]

So they wait for each other.

I'm aware of session locking but no sessions are started and `session.auto_start` is set to `Off`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using the built-in development-only webserver.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

> The web server runs a only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

Comment: I see - I made the example with PHP server to exclude Apache from the equation. It also happens on a Docker setup I have with Apache. So I decided to try again on a third Apache setup - and it worked. So now I'm down to my Docker Apache setup is not working. Any clues what it can be?

Comment: I haven't played with Apache on Docker, but my guess would be whatever image you're using is configured to only handle one concurrent request per container, and that more concurrent requests would be handled by load balancing many such containers.